# Firebase for android: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper

Tags: android, firebase, crash

I have am trying to use firebase database but i can't get rid of the following error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main process:
com.example.useer.instantmessagingapp, PID: 21379
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper 
at com.firebase.client.core.view.QueryParams.<clinit>(QueryParams.java:36)
at com.firebase.client.Firebase.<init>(Firebase.java:182)
```

and here is the gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
  compileSdkVersion 24
  buildToolsVersion "24.0.3"
  defaultConfig {
      applicationId "com.example.useer.instantmessagingapp"
      minSdkVersion 17
      targetSdkVersion 24
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
      proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt')
      'proguard-rules.pro'
          }
      }
  }

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
 exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
 compile('com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.3.1', {
 exclude group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', module: 'jackson-bind'
 exclude group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', module: 'jackson-annotations'
 exclude group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', module: 'jackson-core'
})
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.6.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:9.6.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.6.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.6.1'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

And i added the following to the project level gradle:
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'

Answer (score 1):

Remove following dependancy:

```
 compile('com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.3.1', {
 exclude group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', module: 'jackson-bind'
 exclude group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', module: 'jackson-annotations'
 exclude group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', module: 'jackson-core'
})
```

It is the old library , used for firebase.com , now replaced by :

```
compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.0.1"
```

Comment: Or `9.6.1`. Versions >= 9.0 do not implicitly include Jackson anymore.